# Get a forum most updated post in real time

Tags: web-crawler, web-scraping

There is a very famous forum and I want to get the most updated post in real time and post it on my blog. There is no API of that forum.

I am thinking about send the request to the forum every 5 seconds, check if there is a new post and copy it.

But then everyday I will have to send 7200 requests, which is quite bad, isnt it.

Is there any method/advice for me please?

Answer (score 1):

What about the simple method RSS?

Comment: thanx. I am googling about RSS

Comment: thanx Robin. WHen I tried feed43, it returns a lists of 51 posts of the forum. However, I just wants the latest (51st). Do you have any idea how can I get the latest? There is not pattern difference between all post format, so I cannot get the latest one.

Comment: thankx, at the end, I decided to use get the forum content by myself, using parser. Every 1 min I sent one request to get the data.